# No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [connection refused calling hello on '127.0.0.1:27017']

Tags: php, mongodb, yii2

Yii2 and php  the code is deployed to docker, Mongodb The database is deployed at windows environment。 And the connection succeeds。examine windows vlan and the service is started 127.0.0.1:27017）

Is there any way to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Please write in english.

Answer (score 1):

Use host server's private ip (192.168.?.? / 172.?.?.?) instead of "127.0.0.1" in the php file in docker.

You can also use php 's getenv() function

```
docker run --add-host=host-server:${HOSTIP} ...
```

If it doesn't work, try to edit Mongodb's config file.

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: Using the private IP in the docker network or the name of the server therein solved this for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is related to docker, not yii or mongodb.
You use `127.0.0.1`, This is refrenced to code own docker container and can not see mongodb container. You can use overlay network in same range ip.

for example, this is your docker container in same network:

```
mongodb-container
backend-container
```

your addressing to mongodb should use mongodb-container:27017 or ip address of container.

Also, you can publish mongodb port to public, 0.0.0.0:27017 and just allow to your back-end app to access your mongodb ip and port with firewall.

This is depend on your system architect in networking and server configuration.

Comment: You seem to be the only person on the Internet to mention "should use mongodb-container:27017" I had been trying and trying with different versions of localhost:27017. However, using the name of the mongodb container did the trick. Much thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem as the subject, but my mongo is in a docker container.

The official server has been running for a while without any problems, but it started throwing exceptions last night, and restarting MongoDB is fine.

Here is the command line:

```
docker restart mongo
```